# How to determine the actual position of the image inside an ImageView with Matrix?

Tags: android, matrix, android-imageview

I have ImageView with scale type `ScaleType.MATRIX`.
User can rotate, zoom and drag the image inside it.
What I wanted to know is the actual image x, y position after the changes performed by user?

I try to get the x,y position from it's ImageMatrix

```
Matrix m = new Matrix(); 
m.set(imgView.getImageMatrix()); 
float[] value = new float[9]; 
m.getValues(value); 
Log.d("cutt matrix~~~~~~~~", 
        value[Matrix.MSCALE_X] + " ## " 
        + value[Matrix.MSCALE_Y] + " ## " 
        + value[Matrix.MSKEW_X] + " ## " 
        + value[Matrix.MSKEW_Y] + " ## " 
        + value[Matrix.MTRANS_X] + " ## " 
        + value[Matrix.MTRANS_Y] + " ## " 
        + value[Matrix.MPERSP_0] + " ## " 
        + value[Matrix.MPERSP_1] + " ## "
        + value[Matrix.MPERSP_2]);
```

If user didn't rotate the image, `value[Matrix.MTRANS_X]` & `value[Matrix.MTRANS_Y]` give me the x, y position correctly..
But if the user rotate the image somehow it give the wrong x, y position..

Can anyone explain why? And how to get the correct position after rotation.
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Try to record a point of reference, like the top left corner (x, y) and update its changes every time you alter the image.